# Google and FB auth services - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/rsa/BCRSAPublicKey

Tags: java, maven, bouncycastle, noclassdeffounderror, google-signin

I have added new Bouncy Castle dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

And I get exception mentioned below when I try to use Google Sign in service:

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.x509.CertificateFactory. The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debug
ging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1610)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1281)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1237)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance(CertificateFactory.java:183)
    at com.google.api.client.util.SecurityUtils.getX509CertificateFactory(SecurityUtils.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.refresh(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:171)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.getPublicKeys(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:141)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:191)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/rsa/BCRSAPublicKey
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.generatePublic(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.util.BaseKeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.buildX509Key(X509Key.java:223)
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:170)
```

Other code fragments which use Bouncy Castle library directly work well. I have faced this problem only for Google and FB login services which try to verify token. How to make them work together?

Comment: Is the class `BCRSAPublicKey` in that jar? Bouncycastle might have more than 1 jar you need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for the class on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk14/1.49/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/rsa/BCRSAPublicKey.java), it appears that class is in a different [Bouncycastle jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on/1.54):

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.54</version>
</dependency>
```

Try adding that dependency to your project.